# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError raised when creating a record through services in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having some trouble when I try to create promotion campaigns through the use of `Form Object` and `Service`. In my application, I have `Promotion` of various types, I stored them with Single Table Inheritance in the `:type` column. I have subclasses of promotion types such as `Promotion::CompensationScheme`, `Promotion::CouponCampaign`, `Promotion::RulesMatch` ..etc.

In **promotions/new.html.slim**:

```
= form_for(@promotion_new_form), url: admin_promotions_path do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.select :type
```

the options hash for `:type` select is

```
{'Coupon Campaign' => 'Promotion::CouponCampaign', 'Rules Match' => 'Promotion::RulesMatch'}
```

In **PromotionNewForm** class (Form object), I check the validity of the form fields and pass the creation process to a service called `Promotion::CreateCampaign`.

In **Promotion::CreateCampaign** (Service object):

```
class Promotion::CreateCampaign < AppService

    def initialize params
        @promotion_class = params[:type].constantize
        @params = params.except!(:type)
    end

    def call
        promotion = @promotion_class.new(@params)
        puts promotion.inspect
        SuccessStatus.new(promotion)
    end
end
```

And in my **promotions_controller**:

```
   def create
        results = @promotion_new_form.submit(params[:promotion_new_form])
        if results.success?
            puts results.data.inspect
            # redirect_to edit_admin_promotion_path(results.data)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

And I now have this error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Admin::PromotionsController#create

It is basically stating the line `promotion = @promotion_class.new(@params)` in my service object has forbidden attributes. I know that usually if you handle the form in controllers you will need `strong_parameters` and use `params.permit()` to let the params pass.. But now I am handling it in a service object. I don't know why I still have to do it, if so How can I do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `params[:promotion_new_form]` to your service class. `params` is an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` class. Active Model will apply `strong_parameters` check when it receives an instance of this class to one of its mass assignment methods.

So, you have several options.

### Option 1 (Recommended)

Pass sanitized `params` to your service.

```
results = @promotion_new_form.submit(params.require(:promotion_new_form).permit(:your, :promotion, :fields))
```

### Option 2 (Not recommended)

Pass raw `Hash` of your params to your Service and filter/validate model attributes in there.

```
results = @promotion_new_form.submit(params[:promotion_new_form].to_unsafe_hash)
```

### Option 3 (Last resort)

Don't use mass assignment methods (`create`, `new`, `update_attributes`, etc.), instead initialize each attribute one by one.

```
# Controller
results = @promotion_new_form.submit(params[:promotion_new_form])

# Service
promotion = @promotion_class.new
promotion.field1 = @params.field1
promotion.field2 = @params.field2
SuccessStatus.new(promotion)
```